# offset().top -XX gives different result in Webkit v Firefox/IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, scroll, webkit

I'm trying to implement smooth scrolling to internal anchors on a site with a fixed header.

If I do this:

```
scrollTop: $target.offset().top
```

I get the same results in all browsers, but if I do:

```
scrollTop: $target.offset().top - 100
```

it's fine in Webkit browsers, but in Firefox and IE, after scrolling to the anchor, the page gets jerked up a bit further so the heading is obscured under the header.

The script altogether:

```
$('[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash;
    var $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: $target.offset().top - 100
    }, 900, 'swing', function () {
      window.location.hash = target;
    });
});
```

and a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/tyssen/pen/QwrJmY).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround by adding padding-top to the targets instead.